# Apache FOP 2.0: .ttf to .xml conversion

Tags: java, apache, fonts, apache-fop

I'm trying to obtain `.xml` from `.ttf` in order to embed fonts in Apache FOP for PDF/a conversion (PDF conversion work with without the `.xml`). Can you please help me to do this conversion. Below comes what I tried so far:

I found several website explaining that the conversion shall be done by inputing the folowing line in a CLI open on the directory that contain my `.ttf`:

```
java -cp PATH ; PATH\avalon-framework.jar org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader arial.ttf arial.xml
```

with PATH the path to my `fop.jar`. 
It didn't work and return me: ERROR: Impossible to find the main class

So I tried to use [TTFReader](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop/2.0/org/apache/fop/fonts/apps/TTFReader.java?av=f):

```
     TTFReader read=new TTFReader();
     read.constructFontXML(read.loadTTF(chemin+"Fonts/ttf/arial.ttf", "Arial",true,true), "Arial", "Arial", "C:/Fonts/arial.ttf"  ,chemin+"Fonts/ttf/arial.ttf", true, "Arial");
```

But I didn't understood all the input needed:

```
constructFontXML(TTFFile ttf,String fontName, String className, String resource, String file,boolean isCid, String ttcName)
loadTTF(String fileName, String fontName, boolean useKerning, boolean useAdvanced)
```

I have no idea on how to get the information to set the boolean correctly, nor what is `ClassName` and what purpose serve `ressource` since `path` already exist. My code give me `.xml` but I don't think they are valid.

Comment: Related question from the same user: [FO to PDF/a Conversion with Apache FOP Java Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45435698/4453460)

Comment: I tried to answer you other question; I'm quite sure the XML metrics file are not needed any more.

Comment: Yes, your solution does work and XML files are not requiered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was bypass by lfurini since I finally didn't needed those `.xml` but here is some code that render `.xml` even if I doubt they are configured the right way:

```
         String[] fonts={"Arial", "Courier", "Times New Roman"};
         String[] fontsR={"arial","courier","times"};
         String[] styles={""," Bold"," Italic"," Bold Italic"};
         String[] stylesR={"","bd","i","bi"};
         for (int i=0;i<fonts.length;i++){
             for (int j=0;j<styles.length;j++){
                 String nameFont=fonts[i]+styles[j];
                 String nameTTF=fontsR[i]+stylesR[j];
                 TTFReader read=new TTFReader();
                 Document document=read.constructFontXML(read.loadTTF(chemin+"Fonts/ttf/"+nameTTF+".ttf", nameFont,true,true), nameFont, fonts[i], "C:/Fonts/ttf/"+nameTTF+".ttf"  ,"C:/Fonts/ttf/"+nameTTF+".ttf", true, fonts[i]);
                 Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                 Result output = new StreamResult(new File(chemin+"Fonts/xml/"+nameTTF+".xml"));
                 Source input = new DOMSource(document);
                 transformer.transform(input, output);
```