# FOP 2.1 cannot find Tahoma font

Tags: apache-fop

Im using FOP 2.1 to generate pdf files. It mostly works fine, but there are a number of warnings im trying to get rid of. First thing is to get rid of the missing font warnings:

```
2019-01-24 15:23:30.052  WARN 8772 --- [https-jsse-nio-8087-exec-6] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Tahoma,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
2019-01-24 15:23:30.098  WARN 8772 --- [https-jsse-nio-8087-exec-6] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Tahoma,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
```

Fop config is in fop.xml file and is as such:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <font kening="yes" embed-url="tahoma.ttf" sub-font="Tahoma">
                <font-triplet name="Tahoma" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font kening="yes" embed-url="tahomabd.ttf" sub-font="Tahoma">
                <font-triplet name="Tahoma" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

Fop config is read in as follows:

```
    InputStream inStr = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fop.xml");
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new java.net.URI("."), inStr);
```

Am i missing something or why it is not finding the fonts?

Comment: I think that in the configuration file `kening` should be `kerning`, and the `sub-font` attribute is not needed for ttf files ... but this is probably not the main cause of the problem.

Comment: This [answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552934/4453460) could help (just ignore the pdf/a settings).

Comment: nothing chnged. Still, the same issue.