# HTML to PDF with apache plugin

Tags: java, apache, apache-fop

I want to convert convert HTML file to PDF, but constraint is I have to use only Apache Library(constrain by client) I tried FOP 2.0 but I was unable to do so.
can someone suggest some library or is it possible to do so using FOP?

Comment: this kind of question already exists 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435698/fo-to-pdf-a-conversion-with-apache-fop-java-library

Comment: check this it may help you
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter

Comment: thanks for your reply Talha, but problem with above solutions is one is using .fo and other using .docx file I want to convert .html to pdf

Comment: then go through this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf